# Asp.NET MVC Product> ProductPhoto

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I have 2 Separate Tables Products and Product Photo

When I examine any details in the products table, I want the pictures of that product to come. In that case, I pull it into the Detail table in a field called _UrunFotoPartitialView as @ html.partitial ("") but always

`The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Urun_C7B3883A1159F8EE0177C29B1CA535182B157B3C5BB798ABCC8C2A72FB5CFED9', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'Tututuncu.Models.UrunFotoViewModel'.`

gives an error. How many days I have been dealing but I couldn't do it.

**Ürün Class**

```
 public partial class Urun
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Urun()
    {
        this.Firma = new HashSet<Firma>();
        this.Musteri = new HashSet<Musteri>();
        this.Satis = new HashSet<Satis>();
    }

    public int UrunID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UrunFotoID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> MarkaID { get; set; }
    public string UrunAdi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UrunFiyat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> UrunAlisFiyat { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UrunStok { get; set; }
    public string UrunAciklama { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> UretimYili { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> EklenmeTarihi { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> GuncellenmeTarihi { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Firma> Firma { get; set; }
    public virtual Markalar Markalar { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Musteri> Musteri { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Satis> Satis { get; set; }
    public virtual UrunFoto UrunFoto { get; set; }
}
```

**Ürün Foto Class**

```
public partial class UrunFoto
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public UrunFoto()
    {
        this.Urun = new HashSet<Urun>();
    }

    public int FotoID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> UrunFotoID { get; set; }
    public string BuyukYol { get; set; }
    public string OrtaYol { get; set; }
    public string KucukYol { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Varsayilan { get; set; }
    public string SiraNo { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Urun> Urun { get; set; }
}
```

**My UrunController**

```html
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Tututuncu.Models;

namespace Tututuncu.Areas.Yonetim.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class UrunController : Controller
    {
        private StokDBEntities db = new StokDBEntities();

        // GET: Yonetim/Urun
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return RedirectToAction("Listele");
        }

        public ActionResult Listele()
        {
            var urun = db.Urun.Include(u => u.Markalar).Include(u => u.UrunFoto);
            return View(urun.ToList());
        }


        public ActionResult Yeni()
        {
            ViewBag.MarkaID = new SelectList(db.Markalar, "MarkaID", "MarkaAd");
            ViewBag.UrunFotoID = new SelectList(db.UrunFoto, "FotoID", "BuyukYol");
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Yeni([Bind(Include = "UrunID,UrunFotoID,MarkaID,UrunAdi,UrunFiyat,UrunAlisFiyat,UrunStok,UrunAciklama,UretimYili,EklenmeTarihi,GuncellenmeTarihi")] Urun urun)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Urun.Add(urun);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.MarkaID = new SelectList(db.Markalar, "MarkaID", "MarkaAd", urun.MarkaID);
            ViewBag.UrunFotoID = new SelectList(db.UrunFoto, "FotoID", "BuyukYol", urun.UrunFotoID);
            return View(urun);
        }


        public ActionResult Guncelle(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Urun urun = db.Urun.Find(id);
            if (urun == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.MarkaID = new SelectList(db.Markalar, "MarkaID", "MarkaAd", urun.MarkaID);
            ViewBag.UrunFotoID = new SelectList(db.UrunFoto, "FotoID", "BuyukYol", urun.UrunFotoID);
            return View(urun);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Guncelle([Bind(Include = "UrunID,UrunFotoID,MarkaID,UrunAdi,UrunFiyat,UrunAlisFiyat,UrunStok,UrunAciklama,UretimYili,EklenmeTarihi,GuncellenmeTarihi")] Urun urun)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(urun).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.MarkaID = new SelectList(db.Markalar, "MarkaID", "MarkaAd", urun.MarkaID);
            ViewBag.UrunFotoID = new SelectList(db.UrunFoto, "FotoID", "BuyukYol", urun.UrunFotoID);
            return View(urun);
        }

        public ActionResult Sil(int id)
        {
            var silinecekUrun = db.Urun.Find(id);
            if (silinecekUrun == null)
                return HttpNotFound();
            db.Urun.Remove(silinecekUrun);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Urun");
        }



        public ActionResult UrunResimEkle(int id)
        {
            Urun urun = db.Urun.Find(id);
            ViewBag.Foto = urun;
            return View(urun);
        }

        public ActionResult FotoListele(int id)
        {
            Urun urun = db.Urun.Find(id);
            ViewBag.Foto = urun;
            return View(urun);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult UrunResimEkle(int uId, HttpPostedFileBase fileUpload)
        {

            if (fileUpload != null)
            {
                Image img = Image.FromStream(fileUpload.InputStream);

                Bitmap kucukResim = new Bitmap(img, ResimAyar.UrunKucukBoyut);
                Bitmap ortaResim = new Bitmap(img, ResimAyar.UrunOrtaBoyut);
                Bitmap buyukResim = new Bitmap(img, ResimAyar.UrunBuyukBoyut);
                string buyukYol = "/images/UrunFoto/Buyuk/" + Guid.NewGuid() + VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);
                string ortaYol = "/images/UrunFoto/Orta/" + Guid.NewGuid() + VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);
                string kucukYol = "/images/UrunFoto/Kucuk/" + Guid.NewGuid() + VirtualPathUtility.GetExtension(fileUpload.FileName);

                kucukResim.Save(Server.MapPath(kucukYol));
                ortaResim.Save(Server.MapPath(ortaYol));
                buyukResim.Save(Server.MapPath(buyukYol));

                UrunFoto rsm = new UrunFoto();
                rsm.BuyukYol = buyukYol;
                rsm.OrtaYol = ortaYol;
                rsm.KucukYol = kucukYol;
                rsm.UrunFotoID = uId;
                if (db.UrunFoto.FirstOrDefault(x => x.UrunFotoID == uId && x.Varsayilan == false) != null)
                    rsm.Varsayilan = true;
                else
                    rsm.Varsayilan = false;
                db.UrunFoto.Add(rsm);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return Redirect(ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString());
            }
            return View(uId);

        }



        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

**Urun View Page**

```html
@model IEnumerable<Tututuncu.Models.Urun>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ürüne Resim Ekle";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Yonetim/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<!-- Page Content -->
<div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row bg-title">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-12">
                <h4 class="page-title">File Upload</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-8 col-md-8 col-xs-12">
                <ol class="breadcrumb">
                    <li><a href="/Default.aspx">Yönetim Paneli</a></li>
                    <li class="active">File Upload</li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            <!-- /.col-lg-12 -->
        </div>
        <!-- .row -->


        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12 ol-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <div class="white-box">
                    <h3 class="box-title">File Upload1</h3>
                    <label for="input-file-now">Your so fresh input file — Default version</label>
                    <form action="/Yonetim/Urun/UrunResimEkle" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <input type="hidden" name="uId" value="@Model" />


                        <input type="file" name="fileUpload" />
                        <input type="submit" name="name" value="Kaydet" class="btn btn-primary" />

                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>


           @Html.Partial("FotoListele")

    </div>
</div>
```

**My Partitial View Page**

```html
@model IEnumerable<Tututuncu.Models.UrunFoto>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "FotoListele";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Yonetim/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>FotoListele</h2>


<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.BuyukYol)
        </th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.BuyukYol)
        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Comment: Okey let me transtlate it sorry.

Comment: Show us the the `@model` line you have inside razor page. It's looks like it expected one type and he gets another.

Comment: Okey i edit post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two model types.

Parent: `@model IEnumerable<Tututuncu.Models.Urun>`
Partial: `@model IEnumerable<Tututuncu.Models.UrunFoto>`

You're calling Partial using `@Html.Partial("FotoListele")`
You can use `@Html.Partial("FotoListele", THE-NEW-MODEL-OF-LIST-UrunFoto)`

When using Partial without passing the new model, it uses the parent model. Thus, it gets exception when trying to perform the casting.

You can either create a new Model that fits the Partial needs, or accept the parent model.

**Note:** `partial class` doesn't relate at all to razor engine Html.Partial. more on that [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods)